# How does scoring work in Танкодром (Tank Training)?

Tags: tank-training

In [a report by Anjel Van Slyke and Connal Hughes](http://35summers.org/2010/01/05/the-museum-of-soviet-video-games/) about the [Museum of Soviet Arcade Machines](http://15kop.ru/en/museum/) they've [got a video of *Танкодром* (*Tankodrom* / *Tank Training*)](http://www.flickr.com/photos/a_dangerous_business/4218030081/) which is some kind of open-field magnet-driven tank arcade game.

They couldn't figure out how it was scored though, and watching the video I can't either. Shooting tanks seemed to have random effects and driving through one area inexplicably wrapped around the score counter.

How does aiming and scoring work in this game?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're supposed to destroy all of the stationary targets before your tank is immobilized. You can only 
 start firing once you approach the firing line (indicated by a red line) at a 90° angle.

You get one point per target and you can get them in any order. If the score goes over 52, it will wrap around and go back to zero. The score will also reset if you move the tank over the mine field, and then you can start all over again until the game time runs out.

If you hit 10 or more targets, you get to play a bonus round after the regular game time runs out and its score will be added to the overall score of your game.

(Sourse: [WIkipedia](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC_(%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82)))